# How to tell WebStorm or PhpStorm that the code is inside an async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, phpstorm, webstorm, jsdoc

I am writing code that will be evaluated inside asynchronous function. This code is not wrapped in a function in this file, so all "await"s are underlined as inspection errors.

Is there a way to tell IDE that it is asynchronous context and all "await"s are ok?

**UPD 1:**

*Code evaluation:*

```js
const m = {};
const AF = Object.getPrototypeOf(async function(){}).constructor;
async function evl(n){
    if(typeof m[n] === t.U) await (new AF('imp', 'exp', await get('http://localhost/mdl/' + n + '.js')))(imp, o=>{m[n]=o});
    return m[n];
}
```

*Code source:*

```js
const message = await imp('message'); // await gives inspection error.
exp((name)=>console.log(message + ', ' + name + '!'));
```

Comment: You can [suppress certain inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/code-inspection.html#access-inspections-and-settings) for that file but I'm more curious to see what your code looks like and how you are evaluating it? Maybe there's a way to write what you want without bending the rules?

Comment: @chazsolo added some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 2020.2, the **JavaScript and TypeScript | Async code and promises | Top-level 'await' expression** inspection is turned off by default; if it's enabled for you, try disabling it in **Settings | Editor | Inspections**